# VS 2019 Project Target Framework Not Installed - .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version

Just installed VS 2019 Pro on a new system.  When I open a solution with .net 4.0 project, I get this error: Project Target Framework Not Installed.

[image]

When I choose download it, it goes here but does not have option for .net framework 4.0.

In project settings there is no option for .Net Framework 4.0 in targeting framework:

[image: VS2019 on new machine without .Net Framework 4 target framework]

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk

I have tried installing 4.6.2, 4.5.2, etc.

How can I get this project to open?  It opens on my other machine. It has these options for Target framework in project settings:

[image: VS2019 on other machine with .Net Framework 4 target framework]

Please don't say change the framework version, we need this older version for very old computers running XP and Win 7 that cannot be upgraded.

thank you

Comment: Your .csproj should be pretty old. Considering the compatibility issue you might want to use Visual Studio 2012 instead: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202012&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads which .NET 4.0 should be built-in in the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go directly to their download site.  As shown in another correct answer that was downvoted, it's still available even though it's past end-of-life.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72870727/9008140

You can package the install files with your app just in case, although most likely your installer will see that it's missing and download it anyway.

Comment: thanks but i need the developer targeting pack not the runtime...

Comment: are you sure about that?  The 4.0 download says the runtime contains everything you need to run and develop apps.

Comment: huh yeah i do see that, perhaps you are right, well it won't let me install it and I can't open project still.  says "1. Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4 redistributable. <A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164207">More information</A>. 

2. Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer."

Comment: you may have to develop in a vm running xp.  I've never tried rolling back that far.  I would suggest trying something off-the-wall:  You can develop the app using a newer .net version (4.8) and lower the version back to 4 when you publish.  I had to do that once when i didn't have permission to update the installed .net on a school computer.

Comment: thanks for reply.  what is strange is last fall I built a dev system and it is no problem., i was able to install .net 4 runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You can try downloading .Net 4.0 here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net40

Mandatory warning: Installing an old, unmaintained .Net framework comes with security risks. It's up to you to determine how much those Windows XP PCs are vulnerable and manage said risks.

Comment: thanks but i need the developer targeting pack not the runtime...

Comment: thanks for clearing that up.  Your only choice then (and i do mean only) is to install vs 2012 side-by-side.  It will also install the net framework you need and you can access it from 2019.